# Active Directory Attributes and Dynamic Distribution groups

Tags: active-directory, exchange, attributes

Wondering if someone can help with  my scenario.

When I right click my user account in AD and go to Attribute Editor, we have a attribute called roomNumber which is a Unicode string.  In the field my building location is filled in (Red building).

All users have this but have different buildings in this field.

I would like to do 2 things.

How can I set up a dynamic distribution group to pull data from this field?
For example, all users in the Blue building receive mails from the blue dynamic distribution group.  All users from the red building receive mail from the Red dynamic distribution group.

The issue I am having is extracting this information and pointing it to the right Dynamic distribution groups.

I would also like to know where or how to view what data is attached to the roomNumber field in AD?

I have inherited this so I'm not familiar at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the roomNumber filled  in? Are all roomnumbers of the redbuilding the same?

And If the roomnumber is filled in office , try typing below command in EMS

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Bluebuilding" -RecipientFilter {office -eq 'blue'}

New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Redbuilding" -RecipientFilter {office -eq 'red'}
```

Note:red means the roomnumber of the redbuilding

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, is there any update?If the issue has been resolved. I'd appreciate it if you choose the most helpful post above and mark it as the best answer, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well. Thanks!